# Connecting to MySQL database hosted on remote server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Recently i have purchased a domain "domain.com". The hosting company has the usual CPanel to handle databases.

Using the "MySQL Databases" I:

1. Created a database with the name "database1"
2. Created a user with the username "user1" and password "pass1"
3. Added user "user1" to the database "database1"

So far so good.

After that i clicked on PHPMyAdmin and redirected to the PHPMyAdmin webpage. There i see the "database1" that i have previously created. Clicking on that database, i used IMPORT to import a very simple table named "test" [columns (id,name,surname)]. Importing the table created table "test" below the database "database1", which is correct.

After that i have tried to connect to that database using the code below (`connect_to_db.php`):

```
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("domain.com","user1","pass1","database1");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() ."<br>";
}
```

I have uploaded the `connect_to_db.php` into the `/home/domain/public_html/`.

When i try to connect to the database1 i get the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'user1'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES) in /home/karkoona/public_html/connect_to_db.php on line 13
```

Where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is the public IP of domain.com (if i get it right).

Also on the right of landing page of PHPMyAdmin i see:

```
user: domain@localhost
```

Any idea why i cannot access the database with the current user? 
Is there any mistake in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: `user1` does not have right to access that database.so use root user to give the privileges to `user1`

Comment: your hosting provider may have document along with sample connection ... check it

Comment: When creating the users, you have to create them with the correct "Host" field: Start with username "user1", host "%", password "whatever" and work your way up

Comment: @christostsang check the 2nd part of my answer about cPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant access to user1 using it's IP to access the remote server:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database1.* to 'user1'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass1';
```

NOTE: replace the relevant info to the current info such as `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to the current server IP that will access the remote MySQL.

---

**Since you're using cPanel you can do this to allow the IP:**

- Login to your cPanel (if not already logged in).
- Scroll down to the Databases section.
- Click on the Remote MySQL icon.
- Enter the IP address of the computer that will be making the remote connection.
- Click the Add Host button.

Comment: Adding the IP address into the Remote Database Access host did the trick! To be honest i have tried it before but i used the domain.com instead of the IP and it didnt saved it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It may be beacuse :

```
1) User name or password you are using is wrong
2) User may not have privillage to access the database
```

Answer (score 0):

**you are not pass $con in connection check**

```
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
```

replace it with

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add your server IP address to Remote Database Access Hosts in cpanel. It will allow access to your database and the same method is used to allow access when you are using localhost. But all you have to do is to add your computer IP address into remote database.